# Continue if element is not visible in protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to check if an element is visible and if it's not, I want my test to continue with something else.

The problem is that if element is not visible, nothing seems to be working... I've already tried `isDisplayed()`, `isPresent()`, `invisibilityOf()`... but test fails if element is not visible.
Eg.

```
 element(myElement).isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
      if (result) {
      //do something
      }
    else {
     //do something else
     }
    }
```

This works just fine if myElement is present. But if not, test fails with error: No element found using locator: `By.cssSelector(myCss)`. So somehow it doesn't resolve the promise returned by `isDisplayed()`, so it never goes to else section.
What can I do to keep my test running if element is not displayed?

Comment: I am in same situation.Do we have any correct solution for the above question?

Answer (score 2):

You can chain promises to resolve this issue. This function will return true only if element both is present and is displayed.

```
var isApproachable = function(element) {
  return element.isPresent().then(function(present) {
    return present
      ? element.isDisplayed()
      : false;
  });
}

isApproachable(myElement).then(function(approachable) {
  if (approachable) ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunatelly this doesn't solve my issue. What I need is something like this: if (myElement is displayed) { //do something} else {do something else}. This works fine with isDisplayed() if element is there, but if my element is not present, it will never go to else section, it always fails...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. You can still access boolean value inside of the resolved promise: isApproachable(myElement).then(function(approachable) {
  blabla
});

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, `isDisplayed` requires an element actually be rendered in the browser. `isPresent` means the element is listed in the dom (and/or visible).

`isDisplayed` will fail if the element doesn't exist, so you can't use it to test for existence. You need to use `isPresent`.

You can test this thusly:

```
describe('isPresent', function() {
    it('should not fail if element does not exist', function() {
        browser.get('http://google.com');
        // this will fail if you use isDisplayed
        $('#doesNotExist').isPresent().then(function(inDom) {
            if(inDom) {
                console.log('I EXIST!!!!1!');
            } else {
                console.log('NOT HERE...');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trap the error in an empty function. This is however dangerous if a different error occurs besides the "No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(myCss)" error you get, such as "Stale element".

```
element(myElement).isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
  if (result) {
    //do something
  }
  else {
    //do something else
  }
}.thenCatch(function(err) {};
```